# Celery workers not discoverable while running it over docker compose

Tags: docker, redis, celery

I am running a celery worker container together with backend and frontend container.
Tasks can be perfectly scheduled when I am calling `task.delay()` from the backend container. However, running `task.delay()` from host machine will not lead to execution, but also not a connection error.

More, when I execute `celery -A proj status`, I get `Error: No nodes replied within time constraint`. Even though, the workers look perfectly fine on the docker-compose logs

Here is a minimal example of my docker-compose:

```
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./src/backend/
      dockerfile: ../../docker/backend/Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./data/backend:/data
      - ./src/backend:/src/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.backend
    environment:
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
    stdin_open: true 
    tty: true        

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:7.0.10-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: ./src/backend/
      dockerfile: ../../docker/backend/Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./data/celery_worker:/data
      - ./src/backend:/src/
    environment:
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
    env_file:
      - ./.env.backend
    command: celery -A processing.celery.celery_tasks worker -l info --uid=nobody --gid=nogroup
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - redis
```

My celery version is 5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)